# Cannot add constraints with anchors even after adding subview

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I'm new to iOS. Here is my code causing the error.

```
FSImageView *imageView = [_imageViews objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) page];
if ((NSNull *) imageView == [NSNull null]) {
        imageView = [self dequeueImageView];
        if (imageView != nil) {
            [_imageViews exchangeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) imageView.tag withObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) page];
            imageView = [_imageViews objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) page];
        }
    }

    if (imageView == nil || (NSNull *) imageView == [NSNull null]) {
        imageView = [[FSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, _scrollView.bounds.size.width, _scrollView.bounds.size.height)];
        UIColor *backgroundColor = barsHidden ? _backgroundColorHidden : _backgroundColorVisible;
        [imageView changeBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
        [_imageViews replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger) page withObject:imageView];
    }

    imageView.useScaleFactor = self.useScaleFactor;
    imageView.image = _imageSource[page];
if (imageView.superview == nil) {
        [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];

        if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
            [imageView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
                                                constant:0.0].active = YES;
            [imageView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
                                                   constant:0.0].active = YES;
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
```

The exception occurs at Anchor stuffs. It says..

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code at this point

```
[imageView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
                                            constant:0.0].active = YES;
[imageView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
                                               constant:0.0].active = YES;
```

You are trying to activate the constraint with respect to the superView(i.e your self.view) of superView(i.e your scrollView) **That's illegal**

> Your structure is like UIView -> ScrollView -> imageView. and your are setting anchor from your UIView, you should try setting it relative to ScrollView.

**EDIT**

Your should try this:

```
[imageView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_scrollView.topAnchor
                                                constant:0.0].active = YES;
[imageView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_scrollView.bottomAnchor
                                                   constant:0.0].active = YES;
```

also, set for **.leftAnchor and .rightAnchor.**

**EDIT**

```
[_scrolLView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
                                                constant:0.0].active = YES;
[_scrolLView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
                                                   constant:0.0].active = YES;
```

also, set for **.leftAnchor and .rightAnchor.**

Try and share the results.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm just fixing the error and this code is not mine. Perhaps UIView -> ScrollView -> imageView. Then what should i do next? I'm not familiar with Objective-C at all. :)

Comment: Please checkout my edits. that will give you the idea

Comment: Done, but another error is coming.. like -> A constraint factory method was passed a nil layout anchor.  This is not allowed, and may cause confusing exceptions. Break on BOOL

Comment: You are passing some nil values, that leads to crash. have you set the proper constraints to scrollView in your storyboard? OR you are adding the scrollView as a subView in your code?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't see scrollView in storyboard. There's only collectionView. scrollView is declared at .h file as @property(strong, nonatomic) . I don't know what that means.

Comment: means only that scrollView is defined in .h file. If there is something like @property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *_scrollView then it has some outlet connected in storyboard. You should first set the constraints on your scrollView. and then to your imageView. Checkout my edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178131/discussion-between-bhavin-kansagara-and-zin-win-htet).